# reload webpage on text file change nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to automatically reload my webpage as the content of a text file changes. I did not find any function for this. I am new into nodejs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could implement some AJAX polling method or even implement socket communication between your server and client. As it currently stands though, your question is not really a good fit for the [so] format. We usually require a question to show some research effort and display any attempts that you have already made.

Comment: I would recommend looking into polling your server with an AJAX request. Take a shot at implementing that solution and if you come across any additional issues, come back to the site and post a question that includes any relevant code/error messages that you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

> **Nodemon** is an "**app wrapper**" that monitors file changes in your
>   Node.js project to automatically restart the node server.

To use `Nodemon`:

- Install using `npm: $ npm install -g nodemon`
- Run app with `$ nodemon -L myapp.js` rather than `$ node myapp.js`
- Monitor multiple directories: `$ nodemon -L --watch ~/workspace/mylib --watch libs app/server.js`

Comment: Restarting the server is not the same thing as getting the client to refresh or re-request resources. This is not the correct answer. The server will restart but the client will still be displaying the same content.